# Regex to match specific string with predefined chars before

Tags: regex

I need to write a string that gives me the chance to extract a part of string.

In the following cases I need to extract ES_ (as country code) but only in cases 1 and 2, because as you can see in case 3 that part of string ES_ appears but as part of a wider text SALES_

1. Beginning of string: **ES**_MF_FB-Paid_UCB_SpecialContent_AdventCalendar_Drivetosite_2019-12-16
2. Mid of string: MF_FB-Paid_UCB_SpecialContent_**ES**_AdventCalendar_Drivetosite_2019-12-16
3. Any position of the string but has to be ignored: IT_MF_FB-Paid_UCB_SPECIALSAL**ES**_AdventCalendar_Drivetosite_2019-12-16

I was able to use ^(?:[^*]**){4}([^_]*) to get it on case 2, but I don’t know how to modify it to:
- extract it if it’s at the beginning (or end) of string
- ignore it if it has something different than underscore after or before that part of string

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a negative lookbehind `(?<!` is supported, you could assert what is directly on the left is not any char except an underscore using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

```
(?<![^_])ES_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TjNcWM/1/)

Or if you only want the `ES` part:

```
(?<![^_])ES(?=_)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kSQyLC/1)

---

If lookarounds are not supported, you could assert the start of the string or match an underscore using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and use a capturing group for the `ES` part and match the following underscore

```
(?:^|_)(ES)_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lBNAfr/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^|_)ES_
```

> `ES_`MF_FB-Paid_UCB_SpecialContent_AdventCalendar_Drivetosite_2019-12-16
>   IT_MF_FB-Paid_UCB_SPECIALSALES_AdventCalendar_Drivetosite_2019-12-16
>   MF_FB-Paid_UCB_SpecialContent_`ES_`AdventCalendar_Drivetosite_2019-12-16